# Wordpress Plugin Broke My Site & Cant Figure Out How To Resolve?

Tags: php, database, wordpress, plugins

Ok so long and short of this is, I built a custom plugin for a Wordpress site and was working on a small update. Think perhaps I have a small typo error in the code but after saving the update my site is now showing a 500 error.

I have already attempted the following usual methods without success:

1: renamed the plugin and plugins directories to attempt to both disable individual/all plugins.

2: disabled all plugins via db.

Now the change itself was made via the wp back end, which updated the file. However I cannot see this change via FTP. This baffles me. I would assume somehow the database updated the file somewhere within itself which is perhaps overriding the original file? I haven't seen Wordpress do this before.

I'm not sure but would like to be able to figure out why this happened and if it's fixable.

For now I am just going to do a rollback. Any thoughts on this would be most welcome.

Comment: Have a look at your error log

Comment: The very first thing you always do on a 500 error, is you go check the relevant log files.

Comment: @Scriptman I understand why the error occurred, what I don't understand is why via FTP i am not seeing the updated file in order to resolve. 

As the file was edited by the wp-admin console is the file perhaps cached/stored and overriding the original via the db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you try:

- restoring the database. If you can’t see which file changed probably means that the database was changed and not a specific file. A popular plug-in for back up and restoration is updraft plus which enables you to select files, the database, or themes. Assuming you don’t have a restore plugin installed you could contact your hosting provider who may be able to restore the database to an earlier version. This functionality may also be available through the control panel on the Domain and Hosting.  If this works then at least you know where the trouble lies with your dog and development.

Comment: @Nick do you know an actual file was changed or just a db entry?

Comment: this is exactly the approach I have taken. The files via file manager look as expected. The rollback has been requested.

I know the file that was edited, just a plugins route php file. Also cleared server cache

Comment: Another question would be, where does wordpress store plugin file data assuming it was edited via db